# Combine multiple trained CNN model weight files in one file

Tags: python, merge, model, conv-neural-network

I have CNN model trained on multiple dataset and accordingly I have multiple saved model weights files `(model_1.model, model_2.model, model_3.model)` and multiple labels files `(label_1.pickle, label_2.pickle, labl_3.pickle)`. I want to combine all of models files in one model file `(all_models.model)` and `(all_label.pickle)`, how can I do that? can I do the following:

```
    all_models = model_1 + model_2 + model_3
```

Can anyone please help me, any tip will be useful. Regard...

Comment: are you trying to make the model export cleaner or are you trying to add the three weights of the same model together (which doesn't make a lot of sense)

Comment: @Jaxon thank you for your reply. I want to ad the model weights together because my testing data (unseen data) are mixed and I want to compare all of them with the overall models weights, because I don't know the specific tested data belong to any of the trained model weights. Can you please help me, have you any idea what should I do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: first and foremost, the sum of three weights doesn't actually have a meaning mathematically since CNN filters tend to shift around with each training session. However, if you want to sum of all three models, you can add a non-trainable layer at the end expressed as tf.sum([all three model output layers]) and use this graph as the inference model. Please let me know if that makes sense.